# How to implement inline editing on datatables in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, datatables, inline-editing

I am trying to implement inline editing on datatables in AngularJS. I was trying to find some example but i couldn't. There is a good example [here](https://editor.datatables.net/examples/inline-editing/simple), but it is not compatible with AngularJS. So, how can i implement it in AngularJS?

Related code from my project:

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="meal in meals">
        <td>{{ meal.id }}</td>
        <td>{{ meal.name }}</td>
        <td>
            <a ng-click="open_yemek('lg', meal.name, meal.recipe, meal.ingredients)">Tıklayın</a>
        </td>
        <td class="text-center">
            <!--<small class="label label-warning" style="font-size: 9px !important;"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> {{ yemek.sure }}</small>-->
            {{ meal.time }}
        </td>
        <td>{{ meal.category }}</td>
        <td>{{ meal.region }}</td>
        <td>{{ meal.user }}</td>
        <td class="text-center">{{ meal.rank }}/10</td>
        <td>{{ meal.status }}</td>
        <td>
            <i ng-click="editItem($index)" class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <a ng-click="removeItem('yemekler',$index)"><i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            <a ng-click="addItem('yemekler')"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

This is the JS:

```
$scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
    .withOption('lengthMenu', [5, 10, 15])
    .withOption('autoWidth', true);

$scope.meals = {};

mealFactory.get()
    .success(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        $scope.meals = data;
    });
```

[image: the image]

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion here is to use an ng-include with `<input>` tags inside the td element.
This way, you will be able to have a "readonly" td and an editable one with a single click on it.

Your HTML code of your table should be something like this:

```
<tbody>
   <tr ng-repeat="row in data track by $index"> 
      <td> </td>
      <td ng-click="makeEditable($index)" ng-include="{{row.isEditable ? 'editableInput.html' : 'readonly.html'}}"> </td>
      <td> </td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

With the use of some templates:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="editableInput.html">
     <input type="text" ng-model="row.value"></input>
</script>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="readonly.html">
     <span>{{row.value}}</span>
</script>
```

And in your controller, the click listener:

```
$scope.makeEditable = function($index){
   //remove every previous editable input...
   if($scope.lastDataEditable != null)
      $scope.lastDataEditable = false;

   $scope.data[$index].isEditable = true;
   $scope.lastDataEditable = $scope.data[$index];
}
```

Beware: you haven't provided any form of code, and your question is a bit too general. I provided you a general idea of you should do.

In fact, you should also consider to use a directive for the same purpose: it all dipends of the complexity of your environment.

Comment: I was try to change my code with your advices but i couldn't so i added my form of code.

Comment: The JS code is added. The displayed data is retrieving from database.

Comment: You aren't using ng-include properly. please see my answer on how to use it.